# Im trying to implement a FJF and SJF nonpremptive and premptive scheduling but im getting stuckon the SJF

Tags: java, process, operating-system, scheduling

implement the SJF algorithm in both "Non-preemptive" and "Preemptive" mode
I need to print out the correct execution order of the sequence of process, you need to print them out in the console, e.g. 5, 3, 1, 2, 4, ...  (each number is the process ID), computing and printing out the average waiting time, computing and printing out average response time.

This is the code that I have tried so far i need help with the /*CPU scheduling algorithm 2: shortest job first (SJF), non-preemptive or preemptive mode, section ....

```
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class Process {

    int id; //The unique ID for each process
    Instant ready_time; //store the time that the process arrives at the ready queue
    int burst_time; //the time requires CPU to execute the process
    Instant finish_time; //The time that the current process is finished by CPU
    Instant start_time; //The time that the CPU picks the process for execution
    
    
    String status;
    
    Process(int id)
    {
        this.id = id;
        status = "new";
    }
    
    
    
    /*
     * Display the process info: [id]: ready_time, burst_time
     * */
    void disp()
    {
        System.out.println("["+id+"]: ready: " + ready_time.atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC).getSecond() + "." + ready_time.atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC).getNano() + ", CPU: " + burst_time);
        System.out.println("          start: " + start_time.atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC).getSecond() + "." + start_time.atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC).getNano() + ", finish: " + finish_time.atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC).getSecond() + "." + finish_time.atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC).getNano());
    
    }
    
    void run() {
        status = "running";
        System.out.println("Process " + id + " is running...");
        
        terminate();
    }
    
    void terminate() {
        status = "terminated";
        System.out.println("Process " + id + " is terminated");
    }
    
    /*CPU scheduling algorithm 1: first come first serve*/
    public static void fcfs(List<Process> list)
    {
        //Hold all the processes that have been executed
        List<Process> finished_list = new ArrayList<Process>();
        
        //As long as there is one or more processes in the ready queue, CPU should execute them
        while(list.size() > 0)
        {
            //Initially assume the first item has the smallest arrive_time
            Instant min_arrive = list.get(0).ready_time; 
            int min_idx = 0;
            
            //Use a loop to compare the "min_arrive" with each process in the list
            for(int i = 1; i < list.size(); i++)
            {
                //Compare each process with the current recorded "min_arrive"
                if(min_arrive.compareTo(list.get(i).ready_time) > 0)
                {
                    min_arrive = list.get(i).ready_time;
                    min_idx = i;
                }
            }
            
            //After the loop you should find the smallest arrive_time
            if(list.size() == 10)
            {
                //The current process is the first of all
                list.get(min_idx).start_time = list.get(min_idx).ready_time;
            }
            else
            {
                //If the current process ready_time is after last process's finish time
                if(list.get(min_idx).ready_time.compareTo(finished_list.get(finished_list.size() - 1).finish_time) > 0)
                {
                    list.get(min_idx).start_time = list.get(min_idx).ready_time;
                }
                else {
                    list.get(min_idx).start_time = finished_list.get(finished_list.size() - 1).finish_time;
                }
            }
            
            list.get(min_idx).finish_time 
            = list.get(min_idx).start_time.plus(Duration.ofMillis(list.get(min_idx).burst_time));
            
        
            //Add the current process to the finish list
            finished_list.add(list.get(min_idx));
        
            //Remove the current process from list
            list.remove(min_idx);
        }
        
        //Print out the finish list order
        System.out.println("Finish list: ");

        double waiting_time = 0.0;
        for(int i = 0; i < finished_list.size(); i++)
        {
            finished_list.get(i).disp();
            
            
            waiting_time += (double)Duration.between(finished_list.get(i).ready_time, finished_list.get(i).start_time).toMillis();
            
        }
        
        //Print out the average waiting time
        System.out.println("Average Waiting Time: " + waiting_time/10.0);
        
    }
    
    /*CPU scheduling algorithm 2: shortest job first (SJF), non-preemptive or preemptive mode, indicated by the 3rd parameter "mode" (0: non-preemptive 1: preemptive*/
    public static void sjf(List<Process> list, Instant cpu_time, int mode)
    {
        //Instead of using the earliest process as the CPU available time, you use random()
        //to generate a random CPU start time
        
    }
    
    
    
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        List<Process> list = new ArrayList<Process>();

        Instant cur_time = Instant.now();
        Random rand_cpu = new Random();
        Instant cpu_time = cur_time.plus(Duration.ofMillis(rand_cpu.nextInt(1000)));
        
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            //Create a process by using "i" as the process ID
            Process p = new Process(i);
            
            //Generate random number between 0 and 2000 by using Random() class
            Random rand = new Random();
            int value = rand.nextInt(2000);
            
            //Use the "millisecond" component of the local time to plus the random number
            // as the ready_time value for the current process
            Duration duration = Duration.ofMillis(value);
            p.ready_time = cur_time.plus(duration);
            
            
            //Generate another random number (between 0 and 2000) to assign the burst_time
            p.burst_time = rand.nextInt(2000);
            p.start_time = p.ready_time;
            p.finish_time = p.ready_time;
            
            //Add this process into the list
            list.add(p);
        }
        
        
        //Display all the process
        for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
        {
            list.get(i).disp();
        }
        
        
        //Perform "First come first serve" CPU scheduling
        //fcfs(list);
        
        
        //Perform "Shortest Job First" CPU scheduling
        sjf(list, cpu_time);
        
        
    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: How can the OS determine which job is shortest?  This class of questions make no sense..

Comment: Also, non-preemptive schedulers, essentially, do not exist outside academia and prehistory.